# Add conditional to object using push method

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, push, for-in-loop

I'm wondering if there is a way to add a conditional in the array push method? I would only like the property 'provinceCodes' to be added to the object when it exists. Instead of doing this in the below if/else...I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way?

```
const generateCountriesArray = (countriesObject) => {
const countries = [];
for (var key in countriesObject) {
    var country = countriesObject[key];

    if (typeof(country.provinceCodes) !== 'undefined')
    {
        countries.push({
            value: key,
            name: country.name,
            provinceCodes: country.provinceCodes
        });
    }
    else
    {
        countries.push({
            value: key,
            name: country.name
        });
    }
}
return countries;
```

};

Answer (score 3):

You can use [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) with [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation). If the result of the expression `provinceCodes !== undefined` is `true`, the short-circuit will evaluate to the object that contains `provinceCodes`, and the spread will add the property `provinceCodes` to the result object. If not the expression will evaluate to `false`. The `false` will be discarded.

```js
const generateCountriesArray = (countriesObject) => {
  const countries = [];
  for (var k in countriesObject) {
    var { key, name, provinceCodes } = countriesObject[k];

    countries.push({
      value: key,
      name,
      ...provinceCodes !== undefined && { provinceCodes }
    });
  }
  return countries;
};


const countriesObject = {
  a: { key: 1, name: 1, provinceCodes: 1 },
  b: { key: 2, name: 2 },
};

console.log(generateCountriesArray(countriesObject));
```

Comment: Thanks Ori. Great answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Anyway you need a conditional statement. May this can reduce the code length:

```js
const generateCountriesArray = (countriesObject) => {
    const countries = [];
    
    for (var key in countriesObject) {
        var country = countriesObject[key];
        
        var newObject = {
            value: key,
            name: country.name
        };
        
        if (country.provinceCodes !== 'undefined') {
            newObject.provinceCodes = country.provinceCodes;
        }
        
        countries.push(newObject);
    }
    
    return countries;
}
```

Also I see you are using `const` so perhaps you can use ES6 syntax, for example

```js
const generateCountriesArray = countriesObject => countriesObject.map((country, key) => {
    const newObject = {
        value: key,
        name: country.name
    };
        
    if (country.provinceCodes !== 'undefined') {
        newObject.provinceCodes = country.provinceCodes;
    }
    
    return newObject;
});
```

Another question, are you really need to make such check? In most cases you just can leave the key `undefined`. In this case the ES6 code will look like:

```js
const generateCountriesArray = countriesObject => countriesObject.map((country, key) => ({
    value: key,
    name: country.name,
    provinceCodes: country.provinceCodes, // here the key migth be undefined
});
```

but if you really want to exclude the undefined key from the new objects, try this

```js
const generateCountriesArray = countriesObject => countriesObject.map((country, key) => ({
    value: key,
    name: country.name,
    ...(country.provinceCodes !== undefined && { provinceCodes: country.provinceCodes })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
countries.push({
    value: key,
    name: country.name,
    provinceCodes: country.provinceCodes
});
```

If country.provinceCodes doesn't exist, then you're just setting that key in the new object to undefined, which is just as good as having it not set for most purposes.

Answer (score 0):

To check if some property is present or not, you could use [in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator that returns **true** or **false** instead of `typeof(country.provinceCodes) !== 'undefined'`

```js
var country = {"provinceCodes":0}

console.log("provinceCodes" in country)

console.log("provinceCodes2" in country)
```

I don't know your `countriesObject` but the simplest way seems to be using [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter), and pass just above code.